# What is "friggen"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, translation

There is a line

> Though it may take all friggen day

in a song "My World" by Avril Lavigne, and I can't find any translation/meaning for the word "friggen". Do you know anything about this word?

Comment: What did you find when you searched for its meaning and why didn’t that help?

Comment: Related: [Why do the British use the word "flipping" for emphasis?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/184991/36187)

Comment: @ColleenV after getting no result from google translate I went to ELL to ask this question. I'm sorry. I had to perform better search.

Comment: @sanyash It helps us to know what you searched for and what the results were. I got results when I searched for "friggen". I'm not sure why you didn't get any.

Comment: @ColleenV as I said, I just used https://translate.google.ru/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=friggen and got "friggen" translated to "friggen" which is useless.

Comment: You should include that information in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/whether-you-say-freakin-friggin-or-frickin-depends-on-where-youre-from

In this case, it's used as a softened version of the F-word.

Comment: It is a euphemism.

Comment: Also "frack",  "fark", and "frell" depending on how much of a nerd you are.

Comment: What is “the f-word” you’re referring to? As long as it isn’t in a title and it isn’t gratuitous, vulgar words are OK to write out. It’s helpful to extract the most relevant parts of the article you’re linking to and quote it in your answer so that readers don’t have to go to another site to understand your answer. It also prevents your answer from becoming useless if the linked article changes or is removed by the other site.

Comment: The discussion about coarse language has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97716/discussion-on-answer-by-valkor-what-is-friggen).